# How to add Ajax loader in while loading the page in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, progress-bar

I want to use an ajax loader while loading the page with transparent background. I tried the following code which displays the loading image but how to cover whole backgroung as transperent. My code is:

```
<div class="UpdateProgress1">
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true">
<ProgressTemplate>
    <img src="image/ajax-loader.gif"  /> Loading ...
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
.UpdateProgress1 {
 color:#fff;
 position:fixed;
 filter:alpha(opacity=50);
 -moz-opacity:0.5;
 -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
 opacity: 0.5;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #000;
 float: left;
 top:18%;
 left:13%;
 width:73%; 
 }
```

If anyone knows any link or any solution please tell me. and in the above css if i add the height property the image get displayed at the page load time without click event.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Iframe with an higher z-index to block the main page.

```
<iframe id="blockPage" src="about:blank" style="display: none; position: absolute;
        z-index: 10; filter: Alpha(Opacity=40) DropShadow(Color=#454545);"></iframe>
```

Use the following functions to show and hide the frame

```
function BlockPageContent()
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById("blockPage");
    if(null != ifrm)
    {
        ifrm.style.display = "block";
        ifrm.style.top = 0;
        ifrm.style.left =0;
        ifrm.style.width=screen.availWidth;
        ifrm.style.height = screen.availHeight; 
    }
}

function ShowPageContent()
{
    var ifrm = document.getElementById("blockPage");
    if(null!= ifrm && ifrm.style.display != "none")
    {
        ifrm.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

and call the above function in the following fashion.

Call BlockPageContent in "InitializeRequest" and ShowPageContent in "EndRequest". "InitializeRequest" and "EndRequest" are eventhandlers of PageRequestManager object.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, which of the following are you trying to do:

1) Load a page and, when the user invokes a post-back, display a loader while waiting for the post-back.
2) Display a loader at the beginning of the page that's actually loading.

From the description, it sounds like the latter.  If so, this is a very uncommon approach.  Depending on the page content, it can be difficult to know when it's truly "done loading."  For an HTML/Javascript setup, your best bet would probably be:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // code to hide the loader animation
  });
```

(Note that you'll need jQuery for this, if you don't have it already.)

Things can get much more complicated if you have content that's delayed for other reasons though, such as waiting for a loaded script to do something or waiting for a browser plugin (such as Flash).

Comment: when user clicks on particular page then i want ajax loader whille loading the page

Comment: If the Ajax loader exists on the page the user is navigating _from_ then it should go away once the new page loads (unless you have some kind of frames setup or something strange in your design).

But if it's on the page the user is navigating _to_ then, being an uncommon approach, you're probably going to have to hide it manually when the document finishes loading.  So far I've yet to come across a more reliable method than $(document).ready() for that, and as I said its reliability is questionable from the user's view depending on the page content.

Comment: The problem with $(document).ready is that it fires as soon as the DOM is loaded, but before all external content (images, css, etc) is in place, which is exactly not what Renu123 wants - which is for the loader to disappear only when all the other content is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a typo in your HTML:

```
<div id="wrappe">
---- Whole code goes here ----
</div>
```

This should be called "wrapper".

Your JavaScript is throwing an error because `document.getElementById("wrapper")` is returning null, which doesn't have a property style.

What browser are you testing this in? You should be seeing a little yellow warning icon in the bottom left of IE's window that will give you some clue that there's a script error.

> Webpage error details
>
> Message: Object required
>   Line: 34
>   Char: 13
>   Code: 0
>   URI: http://localhost:64888/ImageTest.aspx

If you are using Firefox, get yourself a copy of the [Developer Toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) which will give you a nice red exclamation mark and the exact error from JavaScript:

> Error: document.getElementById("wrapper") is null
>   Source File: http://localhost:64888/ImageTest.aspx
>   Line: 34